# Given a solution find the values for a diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, linear-diophantine-equations

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and suppose that every solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ of the Diophantine equation $$ax+by=35$$ is written as
$$x = 7-3t \quad \text{and} \quad y = 7-4t.$$
where $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. Determine the values of $a$ and $b$.

At first, I tried to find the $\gcd(a,b)$ by using the solution of the homogeneous equation, but I got plenty of solutions. Second, if I substitute the equation with the given solutions, I do not know what I can conclude in here. I will appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: After you make the substitution, the resulting equation must hold for ALL values of t $\in \mathbb{Z} $

Comment: Extending the comment of @Lozenges, suppose that $~t~$ *goes* to $~(t+1).~$  Then, the computation of $~ax~$ is affected **how**, and the computation of $~by~$ is affected **how**?  Once you answer these questions, consider that the sum $~(ax + by)~$ **must remain constant**, as $~t~$ goes to $~(t+1).$

Comment: So after the substitution, I obtain that $7(a+b) - t (3a+4b)=35$. Then, I need to solve the equations $a+b=0$ and $3a+4b=-35$, in which the values are $a=35$ and $b=-35$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not quite correct! Replace the values of $\{a,b\}$ in the original Diophantine equation and solve to check your answer.

Comment: Wow you are right! I solve the equation with the values above, but I found that the solutions must be $x=1+t$ and $y=t$, which differs with the proposed in the question. The found values are valid only when $t=1$, not for any $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If $m,n$ are integers and $m+n t=0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, you should be able to conclude that $m=n=0$

Comment: Oh, so I needed to conclude from $7(a+b)−t(3a+4b)=35$ that $7(a+b-5)−t(3a+4b)=0$. Solving this the values are $a=20$ and $b=-15$. Then the diophantine equation is $20x-15y=35$, with solution in the hypothesis. Thank you very much @Lozenges for your patience and explanation for this.

Comment: $t\!=\!0\Rightarrow 7(a\!+\!b)=35\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{a\!+\!b=5}.\,$ $\,t\!=\!1\Rightarrow 35 = 4a\!+\!3b = a\!+\!3(\color{#c00}{a\!+\!b}) = a\!+\!3(\color{#c00}5),\,$ so $\,a=20\ \ $